# How to use both MFRC522 and RDM6300 using a NODEMCU

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I want to use both MFRC522 and RDM6300 readers on a single NodeMCU, the two separate codes for each readers are respectively :

```
/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Example sketch/program showing how to read data from a PICC to serial.
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * This is a MFRC522 library example; for further details and other examples see: https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid
 * 
 * Example sketch/program showing how to read data from a PICC (that is: a RFID Tag or Card) using a MFRC522 based RFID
 * Reader on the Arduino SPI interface.
 * 
 * When the Arduino and the MFRC522 module are connected (see the pin layout below), load this sketch into Arduino IDE
 * then verify/compile and upload it. To see the output: use Tools, Serial Monitor of the IDE (hit Ctrl+Shft+M). When
 * you present a PICC (that is: a RFID Tag or Card) at reading distance of the MFRC522 Reader/PCD, the serial output
 * will show the ID/UID, type and any data blocks it can read. Note: you may see "Timeout in communication" messages
 * when removing the PICC from reading distance too early.
 * 
 * If your reader supports it, this sketch/program will read all the PICCs presented (that is: multiple tag reading).
 * So if you stack two or more PICCs on top of each other and present them to the reader, it will first output all
 * details of the first and then the next PICC. Note that this may take some time as all data blocks are dumped, so
 * keep the PICCs at reading distance until complete.
 * 
 * @license Released into the public domain.
 * 
 * Typical pin layout used:
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *             MFRC522      Arduino       Arduino   Arduino    Arduino          Arduino
 *             Reader/PCD   Uno/101       Mega      Nano v3    Leonardo/Micro   Pro Micro
 * Signal      Pin          Pin           Pin       Pin        Pin              Pin
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * RST/Reset   RST          9             5         D9         RESET/ICSP-5     RST
 * SPI SS      SDA(SS)      10            53        D10        10               10
 * SPI MOSI    MOSI         11 / ICSP-4   51        D11        ICSP-4           16
 * SPI MISO    MISO         12 / ICSP-1   50        D12        ICSP-1           14
 * SPI SCK     SCK          13 / ICSP-3   52        D13        ICSP-3           15
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

constexpr uint8_t RST_PIN = D3;     // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
constexpr uint8_t SS_PIN = D4;     // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  // Create MFRC522 instance

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(230400);       // Initialize serial communications with the PC
    while (!Serial);        // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
    SPI.begin();            // Init SPI bus
    mfrc522.PCD_Init();     // Init MFRC522
    delay(4);               // Optional delay. Some board do need more time after init to be ready, see Readme
    mfrc522.PCD_DumpVersionToSerial();  // Show details of PCD - MFRC522 Card Reader details
    Serial.println(F("Scan PICC to see UID, SAK, type, and data blocks..."));
}

void loop() {
    // Reset the loop if no new card present on the sensor/reader. This saves the entire process when idle.
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
        return;
    }

    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
        return;
    }

    // Dump debug info about the card; PICC_HaltA() is automatically called
    mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));
}
```

and

```
/*
 * A simple example to interface with rdm6300 rfid reader using esp8266.
 * We use hardware uart "Serial" instead of the default software uart driver.
 *
 * Note:
 *     The esp8266 let us use 1.5 uarts:
 *     Serial=uart0=rx+tx, Serial1=uart1=tx only (rx pin is used as flash io).
 *     Here we sawp the uart pins so uart0_rx goes to the rdm6300_tx,
 *     and uart1_tx goes to what used to be uart0_tx-
 *     so debug message goes from Serial1.print(...) to the pc debug terminal.
 *     https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/reference.rst#serial
 *
 * Connections:
 *     | esp8266 | nodemcu | rdm6300 | notes                               |
 *     |---------+---------+---------|-------------------------------------|
 *     | GPIO-01 | TX      |         | This is TXD0, connect it to GPIO-02 |
 *     | GPIO-02 | D4      |         | This is TXD1, connect it to GPIO-01 |
 *     | GPIO-03 | RX      |         | Leave it unconnected for flashing   |
 *     | GPIO-13 | D7      | TX      | TX level is same 3.3V as esp8266    |
 *     |         | VU (5V) | VCC     | The rdm6300 must be powered with 5V |
 *     | GND     | GND     | GND     |                                     |
 *
 *     * GPIO-01 to GPIO-02 is for debug terminal output.
 *
 * Arad Eizen (https://github.com/arduino12).
 */
#include <rdm6300.h>

#define RDM6300_RX_PIN 13 // can be only 13 - on esp8266 force hardware uart!
#define READ_LED_PIN 16

Rdm6300 rdm6300;

void setup()
{
  /* Serial1 is the debug! remember to bridge GPIO-01 to GPIO-02 */
    Serial1.begin(230400);

  pinMode(READ_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(READ_LED_PIN, LOW);

  rdm6300.begin(RDM6300_RX_PIN);

  Serial1.println("\nPlace RFID tag near the rdm6300...");
}

void loop()
{
  /* if non-zero tag_id, update() returns true- a new tag is near! */
  if (rdm6300.update())
    Serial1.println(rdm6300.get_tag_id(), DEC);

  digitalWrite(READ_LED_PIN, rdm6300.is_tag_near());

  delay(10);
}
```

I tried merging the code but had no good results.
Does anyone know how to get it to use the 2 readers at the same time? There is little to no information on doing that on Google. Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is very busy. Do you need to include all the comments and every bit of code?

How did you try merging them? What do you mean by two readers on one device? What are you trying to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void loop() {
if (  mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {


// Select one of the cards
     if (  mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {



  // Dump debug info about the card; PICC_HaltA() is automatically called
         mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));
    }
 }
  if (rdm6300.update())
    Serial1.println(rdm6300.get_tag_id(), DEC);

}
```